# HTML button open image file with Windows default application

Tags: javascript, html

As the title said, can we do this? Please, tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: depends on the browser

Comment: Well, thanks for your information. I am just curious about this. Can you elaborate @JaromandaX?

Comment: `<a href="img.png" download="img.png"><img src="img.png" /></a>` - when clicked will download the file, in firefox it asks if you want to save or open with default app ... chrome just downloads it ... other browsers will vary

Comment: Yep, firefox will do because they have option to keep default action when download the file.

Answer (score 0):

With pure html, no this is not possible. With some client-side language like javascript, maybe, but whatever way you come up with would not be possible across all platforms or browser. The default image application of the user's computer is outside of the scope of your environment as a developer, which includes the server, the client's browser and whatever variables are alloted to you as the developer.